# BlueJ cannot find a variable

Tags: java, bluej

I'm trying to set up the first  fight, but at line 24, BlueJ tells me that variable `firsthitpoints` is not visible to carry out.

I'd be grateful if someone could tell me what's wrong with this code

```
  if (characterquality == "Slayer"){
        int HP = 150;
        int Attack = 75;
        int Defense = 50;
        int MP = 20;
        int EXP = 0;
        int Gold = 50;

       boolean firstbattle = true;
       while (firstbattle){
          int firstbattlehealth = HP;
          int firstbattleattack = Attack;
          int firstbattledefense = Defense;
          int firstbattleMP = MP;
          int firstbattleEXP = EXP;
          int firstbattlegold = Gold;

          int firstattack = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
          int firstdefense = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);

          int firstenemyattack = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
          int firstenemydefense = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);

          int firstenemyhealth = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 50);

          int firstenemyhitpoints = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 25);
          boolean firstkill = true;
          while (firstkill) {
              if (firstattack > firstenemydefense){
                  int firsthitpoints = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * firstbattleattack);

              }
              int firstenemynewhealth = firstenemyhealth - firsthitpoints;

              if (firstenemynewhealth <= 0){
                  firstkill = false;
              }
              if (firstattack <= firstenemydefense){
                 System.out.println("Attack failed!");
              }
              if (firstenemyattack > firstdefense){
                  int firstenemyhitpointattack = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * firstenemyhitpoints);
                  System.out.println("The enemy did " + firstenemyhitpointattack + " damage to you. You have " + firstbattlehealth + " health remaining.");
               }
              if (firstenemyattack <= firstdefense){
                  System.out.println("Enemy attack missed!");
              }
          }
          int firstenemynewhealth = firstenemynewhealth;
          if (firstenemynewhealth <= 0){
              firstbattle = false;
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Where is "firstattackhitpoints" inyour code?

Comment: Line 24 is where is the error pops up.

Comment: where is line 24? tell us which

Comment: Sorry for the amount of code around it, I just figured it might make more sense if I included more code to get the whole picture. Also, I'm sorry for the wacko variable names, but it's a bit easier for me to keep track of it.

Comment: Line 24 is 2 lines underneath the line that says "while (firstkill) {".  It's also 8 lines up from the bottom if you don't scroll down the code, and 24 lines down from the top of the code block.

Comment: EDIT: Wrong variable name, was changed to "firsthitpoints". I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining the variable in the preceding `if` block, move it outside the block and give it an initial value. Something like,

```
boolean firstkill = true;
int firsthitpoints = 0; // <-- declare and initialize.
while (firstkill) {
    if (firstattack > firstenemydefense){
        firsthitpoints = Math.ceil(Math.random() * firstbattleattack);
    }
    int firstenemynewhealth = firstenemyhealth - firsthitpoints;
    // ...
```

**Also**, and not directly to your question, ***please*** don't compare `String` equality with `==`.

```
if (characterquality == "Slayer"){
```

should be

```
if (characterquality.equals("Slayer")) {
```

Perhaps it works in your case, but that is only testing reference equality (not value equality). See also, [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/2970947)

Finally, there is a *cost*<sup>1</sup> to executing a compare instruction. You should be using `else` blocks, instead of comparing logical inversions with multiple `if`(s). Something like,

```
if (firstenemyattack > firstdefense) { 
    int firstenemyhitpointattack = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() 
            * firstenemyhitpoints);
    // Presumably, firstbattlehealth -= firstenemyhitpointattack here?
    System.out.println("The enemy did " + firstenemyhitpointattack 
            + " damage to you. You have " + firstbattlehealth 
            + " health remaining.");
} else { // <-- An "else" block, firstenemyattack <= firstdefense
    System.out.println("Enemy attack missed!");
}
```

<sup>1<sub>Albeit a very small one in a modern context.</sub></sup>

Comment: Thank you, I'll put this in immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a local variable `firsthitpoints` and initialize it like this:

```
    int firsthitpoints = 0;
          while (firstkill) {
              if (firstattack > firstenemydefense){
                   firsthitpoints = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * firstbattleattack);
```